# htaccess rewrite giving a 404?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have this line in my htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^/events/([^/\.]+)/?$/ /events.php?eventdate=$1 [NC,L]
```

I have a php page events.php that is pulled dynamic dates and generating the content. When people go to /events/04-26-2013/ for example I want it to be pulling from events.php?eventdate=04-26-2013

Any ideas where I am going wrong here? It currently gives me a 404 when I try to load the directory.

Comment: You don't want the slash after the `$` so something like this may work: `RewriteRule ^/events/([^/\.]+)/?$ /events.php?eventdate=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I had that at first and I still got no joy. I am receiving a 404 when I try to view /events/04-26-2013/ even though the php page shows just fine if I go to that directly.

Comment: Is `events.php` located at the document root?

Comment: View your apache logs to check what page the rewrite is changing to and saying doesn't exist.

Comment: Sadly I do not have access to my apache logs (shared hosting) but my shared log simply says "File does not exist:"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is with your first slash.

This should work.

```
RewriteRule ^events/([^/\.]+)/?$ /events.php?eventdate=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: @gearb0x Please consider accepting this answer, when possible.

Comment: @DannyB your belief is correct according to the Apache manual.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [RewriteRule Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) setion of the [mod_rewrite manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) :

> In VirtualHost context, The Pattern will initially be matched against
> the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query
> string (e.g. "/app1/index.html").
>
> In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be
> matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that
> led the server to the current RewriteRule
> (e.g. "app1/index.html" or "index.html" depending on where
> the directives are defined).
>
> If you wish to match against the
> hostname, port, or query string, use a RewriteCond with the
> %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or %{QUERY_STRING} variables
> respectively.

Unless there is a good reason for serving pages from /EVENTS/,/Events/,& /events/ you do not need the `[NC] No Case` declaration. So for [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) the rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^events/([^/\.]+)/?$ events.php?eventdate=$1 [L]
```

In the [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#virtualhost) context it would look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/events/([^/\.]+)/?$ /events.php?eventdate=$1
```